# How to filter all fields data by one time without auto using button in lara classifer(Laravel,php)

Tags: php, laravel

Guys i'm currently working with lara classifer project and filtering method filter data when we select each radio button or dropdown.I want to make a button that can filter all data at one time.so pls help me

```
<!-- this (.mobile-filter-sidebar) part will be position fixed in mobile version -->
<div class="col-md-3 page-sidebar mobile-filter-sidebar pb-4">
    <aside>
        <div class="sidebar-modern-inner enable-long-words">
            
            @includeFirst([config('larapen.core.customizedViewPath') . 'search.inc.sidebar.fields', 'search.inc.sidebar.fields'])
            @includeFirst([config('larapen.core.customizedViewPath') . 'search.inc.sidebar.categories', 'search.inc.sidebar.categories'])
            @includeFirst([config('larapen.core.customizedViewPath') . 'search.inc.sidebar.cities', 'search.inc.sidebar.cities'])
            @if (!config('settings.list.hide_dates'))
                @includeFirst([config('larapen.core.customizedViewPath') . 'search.inc.sidebar.date', 'search.inc.sidebar.date'])
            @endif
            @includeFirst([config('larapen.core.customizedViewPath') . 'search.inc.sidebar.price', 'search.inc.sidebar.price'])
            
        </div>
    </aside>
</div>

@section('after_scripts')
    @parent
    <script>
        var baseUrl = '{{ request()->url() }}';
    </script>
@endsection
```

this is the code that working with searching area...